# Send xml string in HttpRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-400

There is a service that accepts data as an Xml string.

I'm trying to send xml as a serialized string to this service, however I'm getting a 400 error code. What am I doing wrong?

My class for request:

```
public class AltoTrackClient
{
    //private static string _url = "http://ws4.altotrack.com";
    //private static string _action = "/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc?wsdl";

    public static string ProcessXml(string xmlString)
    {           
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://ws4.altotrack.com/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc?singleWsdl");

        byte[] requestInFormOfBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = requestInFormOfBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestInFormOfBytes,0, requestInFormOfBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        string recievedResponse;            
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
            {
                recievedResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return recievedResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the right url in the WebRequest ? Since you have a Wsdl, try to add a service reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Comment: Not really.
Prior to this, ServicePositionsClient was used: System.ServiceModel.ClientBase <IServicePositions>. This class and its interface was generated like this "svcutil.exe http://ws4.altotrack.com/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc?wsdl
"

Comment: I can not use adding a service reference, because we go to the net standard, and this, I'm told, will not be work.

Comment: You may not be able to add a service reference, but you [should be able to build a service client in code](https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little too late to answer this question, since it's been more than 1 year and 9 months from the date this question was asked, but I have some clues on how to solve this issue, if that may help you or someone else.

I worked recently on a project in which I needed to develop a process that communicated with Altotrack web service. I was trying to send some requests to this web service and in the end I just ended up receiving error 400 the same way that it's happening with you. Their documentation is really confusing and unhelpful, to say the least.

After some analyzing and attempts, I find out how the parameters of the POST request must be set so the web service replies with a success message:

URL: 
http://ws4.altotrack.com/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc

Headers:

`Content-Type : text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction : http://tempuri.org/IServicePositions/ProcessXML`

Request payload:
`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:ProcessXML>
      <tem:xmlSerializado>
        &lt;registro&gt;
          &lt;systemUser&gt;AltoWS&lt;/systemUser&gt;
          &lt;password&gt;$Alt0WS&lt;/password&gt;
          &lt;movil&gt;
            &lt;proveedor&gt;My&lt;/proveedor&gt;
            &lt;dominio&gt;ABC1234&lt;/dominio&gt;
            &lt;nroSerie&gt;12345678&lt;/nroSerie&gt;
            &lt;fechaHoraEvento&gt;25-10-2019 12:34:56&lt;/fechaHoraEvento&gt;
            &lt;fechaHoraRecepcion&gt;25-10-2019 12:34:56&lt;/fechaHoraRecepcion&gt;
            &lt;latitud&gt;-22.215328&lt;/latitud&gt;
            &lt;longitud&gt;-49.6559497&lt;/longitud&gt;
            &lt;altitud&gt;666&lt;/altitud&gt;
            &lt;velocidad&gt;20&lt;/velocidad&gt;
            &lt;rumbo&gt;180&lt;/rumbo&gt;
            &lt;codigo&gt;0&lt;/codigo&gt;
          &lt;/movil&gt;
        &lt;/registro&gt;
      </tem:xmlSerializado>
    </tem:ProcessXML>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`

Of course, in the request payload, I added spaces only to be more legible. You can remove them without any issue if you so desire to decrease the size of the request payload.

It was a long time ago I worked with C#, but I analyzed the portion of your code and I'd say that the value that came stored in the parameter xmlString in the method ProcessXml isn't in the format expected by the web service, therefore returning error 400 upon request. That's what was happening to me too.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know how you solved it, but it works! the documentation is a total mess. Thank you!